# Lyx: how to remove textrm mode?

Tags: lyx

For some reason I don't understand (and that I cannot reproduce), Lyx encloses some text with `\textrm{}` when using beamer. How can I change this? Changing *Edit -> Text Style -> Customised* won't do anything.

I cannot reproduce unfortunately how it happens, so cannot give steps on how to recreate it, a minimal file is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6drelcttrz4o71j/pres_text.lyx?dl=0), and this it the outcome, seen with the *View Source*:

```
% Preview source code from paragraph 36 to 38

\textrm{a}

\textrm{Blabla}

\textrm{
\[
Y^{i}(F,j)=y(F^{i}+\alpha_{j}^{i})+\beta_{j}^{i}
\]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to reproduce? Meaning sometimes the same .lyx file produces textrm and sometimes it doesn't? Or meaning you don't know how to recreate a new .lyx file that does it? If you are able to post a minimal example .lyx file i could take a look. By the way, please always give the LyX version that you're using.

Comment: hi @scottkosty, yes I meant it's not clear how this happens. But I attached a minimal Lyx file then. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, although I can't answer how the textrm got in there (ping me if you can come up with a way to construct a .lyx file in a way that should not give textrm but does), I can at least answer how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `\textrm`:

1. Select the text starting with "The yield" and ending with the end of the math equation.
2. Go to Edit > Text Style > Customized.
3. In the dialog, change "Family" to "Reset".

This resets the family setting to the default.